# Sampling from prior without running a separate model

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I want to graph the histograms of parameter estimates from a stan model against the priors for those parameters. I have tried doing this by running a model in stan, graphing it with ggplot2, then overlaying an approximation of the prior distribution using R's random generator function (e.g. `rnorm()`, `rbinom()`) but I have run into many scaling issues that make the graphs impossible to get looking right.

I was thinking a better way to do it would be simply to sample directly from the prior distribution and then graph those samples against the parameter estimates, but running a whole separate model *just* to sample from the priors seems very time-consuming. I was wondering if there was a way to do this within, or rather parallel-to, an existing model.

Here is a sample script.

```
# simulate linear model
a <- 3 # intercept
b <- 2 # slope

# data
x <- rnorm(28, 0, 1)
eps <- rnorm(28, 0, 2)
y <- a + b*x + eps

# put data into list
data_reg <- list(N = 28, x = x, y = y)

# create the model string

ms <- "
    data {
    int<lower=0> N;
    vector[N] x;
    vector[N] y;
    }
    parameters {
    real alpha;
    real beta;
    real<lower=0> sigma;
    }
    model {
    vector[N] mu;
    sigma ~ cauchy(0, 2);
    beta ~ normal(0,10);
    alpha ~ normal(0,100);
    for ( i in 1:N ) {
    mu[i] = alpha + beta * x[i];
    }
    y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
    }
"

# now fit the model in stan
fit1 <- stan(model_code = ms,     # model string
             data = data_reg,        # named list of data
             chains = 1,             # number of Markov chains
             warmup = 1e3,          # number of warmup iterations per chain
             iter = 2e3)         # show progress every 'refresh' iterations

# extract the sample estimates
post <- extract(fit1, pars = c("alpha", "beta", "sigma"))

# now for the density plots. Write a plotting function
densFunct <- function (parName) {
  g <- ggplot(postDF, aes_string(x = parName)) + 
              geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), fill = "white", colour = "black", bins = 50) +
              geom_density(fill = "skyblue", alpha = 0.3)
  return(g)
}

# plot 
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = lapply(names(postDF), function (i) densFunct(i)), ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Now I understand that I can sample from the prior by simply omitting the likelihood from the model string, like so

```
ms <- "
  data {
    int<lower=0> N;
    vector[N] x;
    vector[N] y;
  }
  parameters {
    real alpha;
    real beta;
    real<lower=0> sigma;
  }
  model {
    sigma ~ cauchy(0, 2);
    beta ~ normal(0,10);
    alpha ~ normal(0,100);
  }
"
```

But is there any way to get the samples from the prior within the first model? Maybe via the generated quantities block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

First, if the program is general enough, just pass in zero-size data so that the posterior is the prior.  For instance, `N = 0` in the regression example you gave will work (along with the right zero-sized x and y).

Second, you can write a pure Monte Carlo generator (doesn't use MCMC) in the generated quantities block.  Something like:

```
generated quantities {
  real<lower = 0> sigma_sim = cauchy_rng(0, 2);  // wide tail warning!
  real beta_sim = normal_rng(0, 10);
  real alpha_sim = normal_rng(0, 20);
}
```

The second approach is much more efficient as it conveniently draws an independent sample and doesn't have to do any MCMC.

Comment: Thank you @Bob Carpenter, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: when I included the `cauchy_rng` sampler I got an error but when I removed it and only included the variables based on `normal_rng` it worked. The error was `Chain 1: Exception: model6994159ae8e_5df9bac984f38f4f422d22ee75e72cc6_namespace::write_array: sigma_sim is -8.37644, but must be greater than or equal to 0  (in 'model6994159ae8e_5df9bac984f38f4f422d22ee75e72cc6' at line 26)`. Is the cauchy too wide-tailed?

Comment: @Ilewmills Check this link
https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/generating-block-giving-me-negative-numbers-when-lower-0/6502

Answer (score 1):

The answer to how to do this occurred to me on the bus this morning. Of course by the time I finished writing it out, @Bob Carpenter posted the solution I was looking for. By comparison my way is quite cumbersome and hacky, but it *does* work.

All we need to do is specify priors that mirror the actual priors but which are never passed downstream into a likelihood function.

So in the example above all we need to do is create these mirror variables within the model string. We'll call them `p_alpha`, `p_beta`, and `p_sigma`. These will be analogs of `alpha`, `beta`, and `sigma` but will not appear in any likelihood function.

Note we have to create these variables in the `parameters{}` block and in the `model{}` block.

```
ms <- "
  data {
    int<lower=0> N;
    vector[N] x;
    vector[N] y;
  }

  parameters {
    // priors to sample from
    real p_alpha;
    real p_beta;
    real p_sigma;

    // real priors
    real alpha;
    real beta;
    real<lower=0> sigma;
  }

  model {
    vector[N] mu;

    // priors to sample from
    p_sigma ~ cauchy(0, 2);
    p_beta ~ normal(3,1);  // for didactic purposes
    p_alpha ~ normal(0,100);

    // actual priors
    sigma ~ cauchy(0, 2);
    beta ~ normal(0,10);
    alpha ~ normal(0,100);

    // likelihood
    for ( i in 1:N ) {
    mu[i] = alpha + beta * x[i];
    }
    y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
  }
"
```

Note that the specifications of the distributions for the mirror parameters should match those of the actual priors, which I have done for `p_alpha`/`alpha` and `p_sigma`/`sigma`. For didactic purposes I have deliberately made the centre and spread of `p_beta` different from `beta` as I will graph these below on the same graph.

Now run the model again

```
fit1 <- stan(model_code = ms,     
             data = data_reg,       
             chains = 1,            
             warmup = 1e3,         
             iter = 2e3)
```

And extract the samples

```
post <- as.data.frame(extract(fit1, pars = c("p_alpha", "p_beta", "p_sigma", "alpha", "beta", "sigma")))  

head(post)


# output
    p_alpha   p_beta     p_sigma    alpha     beta    sigma
1 -81.44259 3.275672  -1.1416369 3.121382 2.499459 2.354001
2 161.03740 3.694711   0.2989131 3.648288 2.335520 2.140973
3 126.58106 3.495947  -2.0027929 3.846835 2.266247 3.037055
4  18.55785 3.283425  -0.4045153 2.903958 1.854639 1.807591
5 103.02826 5.213568 -18.3721863 3.980290 1.725396 2.178264
6  49.50477 1.737679   6.5971377 4.209471 2.535044 2.941958
```

Here are the priors and posteriors as separate plots

So now we have raw priors and posteriors for the same parameters in the same dataframe.

Now what if we want to put prior and posterior on the same graph?

First put the two parameters `p_beta` and `beta` into a dataframe, making it long-form so that estimates are in one column and distribution (prior vs posterior) in the other.

```
library(dplyr)
betaDF <- post %>% dplyr::select(grep("^.*beta$", names(.))) %>%
                   gather(key = source, value = estimate) %>%
                   transform(source = factor(ifelse(source == "p_beta", "prior", "posterior"), levels = c("prior", "posterior")))
```

Now graph it

```
ggplot(betaDF, aes(x = estimate, fill = source)) +
       geom_density(alpha = 0.3) +
       coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-5,10)) +
       labs(x = "beta")
```

[image]

Comment: You can pull shared functions like that density definition out into a function to make it easier to keep consistent.  In some cases, you'll have to use MCMC because there won't be an easy way to simulate.  For instance, we don't have truncated RNGs or inverse CDFs, so that's hard to do in generated quantities, but easy with parameters in the model block.